# Application-defined or object-defined error when setting the color of an entire row

Tags: excel, vba

I have this little subroutine that used to work but now it doesn't. I have no idea what I did. It's the worksheet_selection sub so it gets run whenever I navigate to a different cell in the active worksheet or if one of the cells changes on the sheet. All it does is check to see if a certain range of cells is selected and if it does it changes the entire row either green, yellow or white. As soon as I click on one of the target cells I get "Application-defined or object-defined error". Please see my code below. Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.row = 2 Or Target.row = 4 Or Target.row = 6 Or Target.row = 8 Or Target.row = 10 Or Target.row = 12 Or Target.row = 14 Or Target.row = 16 Or Target.row = 18 Then

            With Target.EntireRow.Interior
                If .Color = 16777215 Then 'white
                   .Color = 65280  'green ' this is where the error is given
                ElseIf .Color = 65280 Then ' green
                    .Color = 65535  'yellow
                ElseIf .Color = 65535 Then 'yellow
                    .Color = -4142
                End If
            End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That code runs fine for me in XL 2010, 2013 and 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that if your Worksheet is **Protected**.

So either you unlock the worksheet before the color change, or change the Worksheet Protect method to `.Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

Also you get undesired results with your current code - try highlight multiple cells across some rows, either starts or ends on the rows 2/4/6/8/10/12/14/16/18!

Try understand below:

```
Option Explicit

Private Const C_WHITE As Long = 16777215 ' white
Private Const C_GREEN As Long = 65280 ' green
Private Const C_YELLOW As Long = 65535 ' yellow
Private Const C_NONE As Long = xlNone ' No Fill

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim oRng As Range, oRngApplicable As Range
    Set oRngApplicable = Intersect(Target.Columns(1), Target.Worksheet.Rows("2:18"))
    If oRngApplicable Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    For Each oRng In oRngApplicable
        If oRng.Row Mod 2 = 0 Then
            With oRng.EntireRow.Interior
                Select Case .Color
                    Case C_WHITE:   .Color = C_GREEN
                    Case C_GREEN:   .Color = C_YELLOW
                    Case C_YELLOW:  .Color = C_NONE
                End Select
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: PatricK, Thanks a lot, that is the answer. Thanks for proving I'm not crazy!